# C# + Azure Storage blobs: StorageException: There is currently a pending copy operation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have server that getting a URL of azure blob file (SAS read only) and copy it to another blob in different Storage account. The copy command is async command (`StartCopyAsync()`).

Copy the file is only one thing that this server doing, it's doing some more. If one (or more) of the other calculation failed, it's throw exception.

When exception occurred, I doing rollback - which mean, delete the file I copied in the first stage. I doing it like this:

```
await backupFile.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
```

### The problem

I getting this error code:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (There is currently a pending copy operation.) 
---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: There is currently a pending copy operation.
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption deleteSnapshotsOption, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I guess it because the async copy didn't finished yet...

Is this possible to solve it with async Delete command, that will take place after the Copy command done?

Any other solution will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You could try checking `backupFile.CopyState.Status`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the `StartAsyncCopy()` overload that accepts a **CancellationToken**. Once you use that overload, you should be able to cancel the copy operation through the **CancellationTokenSource** of the **CancellationToken** you used when you called the method.

See [CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopyasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_StartCopyAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) for all available overloads. And you can also take a look at [CancellationTokenSource Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.7.2) on how to use the cancellation mechanism.

**Update**

As mentioned in the comment below, you should also take a look at `CloudBlob.AbortCopyAsync()` in case the operation already started.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, the cancellation token can only cancel the `CloudBlob.StartCopyAsync` operation before the copy has been started. If the async copy has been started on server side, you'd need to abort the copy process by calling `CloudBlob.AbortCopyAsync` method.